# can we sum up and removed some array values in code line only (GAS/JS)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My expected output is to get the total back into the original array. I can achieve this with 2 lines of code below. But could there be another faster way to do it in 1 line only? Thanks.

```
function removeArrVal(){
  var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
  
  arr=arr.map(function(a,i){return a+arr[i+3]}); //sum val in 1 position with the 3rd position after it.
  var removed=arr.splice(3,arr.length-1); // remove the NaN values
  console.log(arr); // [5,7,9]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- chain the `map` and `splice` into 1 line
- chain a `filter` after the `map`
- or just use a plain for-loop to create a new array.

In general, `splice` is considered slower

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
function removeArrVal() {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  (arr = arr.map((a, i) => a + arr[i + 3])).splice(3, arr.length - 1); // remove the NaN values
  console.log(arr); // [5,7,9]
}


function removeArrVal2() {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  arr = arr.map((num, i) => num + arr[i + 3]).filter(num => !isNaN(num));
  console.log(arr);
}


function removeArrVal3() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    arrNew = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 3; arrNew[i] = arr[i] + arr[i++ + 3]);
  console.log(arrNew);
}

removeArrVal();
removeArrVal2();
removeArrVal3();
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Woww! Thanks so much, @TheMaster !  Tested all 3 and the most I like is removeArrVal2(). If you don't mind, for my learning purpose, can you elaborate on `/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/`, please? Or should I create a new question for this? Thanks !

Comment: @dell Like the tag says ignore it. It's just for running the snippet in stackoverflow here.

Comment: I could see more details in the logs when u put this `<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/` . I'll explore it as a new knowledge then. thanks.

Comment: @dell No ignore it. Logs in apps script won't show anything.  It'll only show up here in stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link too, @TheMaster . alrite then, noted.

Answer (score 2):

One liner of your code would be:

```js
const removeArrVal = () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((val, index, arr) => val + arr[index + 3]).filter((_, index) => index < 3);
console.log(removeArrVal());
```

First we map over the array, and we need to use `index` to know the position of the array and `arr` to access specific values of the array because we use an array literal.
Next we filter the array based on the index, filtering out all items that have index above 3.

If you give us more information on what you are trying to achieve, we can help you better.

Comment: This is interesting as it seems to give 1 code line for the whole function. However, I got an error "arr is not defined". Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer made me just realized what param actually each var represents in that bracket after command map `(val, index, arr)` . all the while I kept seeing this being represent with a letter each only and I just made assumptions based on the output after the code line. This is new useful knowledge for me as the beginner. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because sometimes you do not have s way to refer to the array "before the dot" and sometimes you need to have it, it is passed as an argument to map after the current value and current index. Please note that unlike current value and current index, it is always the same for all elements of the array.

Comment: Do you still have a problem running this function?

Comment: Thanks, @IvanD. It works. I understood that the fix was the argument we need to put in the console.log was supposed to be `removeArrVal()` not `arr` . May I know is this `removeArrVal()` is considered a new array after the mapping and the filter or is it a function? Sorry, I'm still a beginner trying to learn as much as possible on GAS/JS. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your question, but `removeArrVal` is a function and `removeArrVal()` is a result of calling this function, which always returns a new array (but with the same content)

Comment: ouh I see. alright.noted with lots of thanks, @IvanD . Appreciate your time and effort to support my questions.